# Ajax response is not working with ACE Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ace-editor

I have a problem related to ace editor(ajax, javascript)..

I am receiving the **AJAX response** in variable content..

```
    var content=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

My **ACE Editor** is like this..

```
    <div id="tabs-1">Some Text</div>

      editor = ace.edit("tabs-1");
      editor.setTheme("ace/theme/eclipse");
      var cMode = require("ace/mode/c_cpp").Mode;
      editor.getSession().setMode(new cMode());
```

Now I tried to put ajax response to div

```
     document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML=content;
```

It is not working then I tried

```
     editor.getSession().setValue(content);
```

It is also not working. I am not able to find out the problem. 
Please help....

Comment: Can you `alert(content)` - what it will return? Or try this one: `document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML='THIS SHOULD BE A CONTENT'`

Comment: @Pavlo alert is showing expected content. but document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML='THIS SHOULD BE A CONTENT' is not working.

Comment: Your should probably provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)